# installing typescript in nodejs taking too long

Tags: node.js, npm, typescript

i was trying to install typescript in my laptop. I am using ms windows 8.1.(64bit). I have installed Node.js 64 bit and executed the command **npm install -g typescript**. The installation started (i think) and all i can see is a rotating '/'. Even after 2 hours i am seeing the same thing. And when i checked the taskmanager the CPU was using morethan 70%. Why is installing typescript takes too long? Is it downloading too many files?. Can some one tell me if there any other way to install and use type script. (I do not want to use visual studio also).

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found the error. Thanks to 'ezrepotein'. I have run the command `npm config ls -l` and found that there was 3 location to Temp directory. I accidentally added path to jdk and jre in Temp. I deleted that so *Temp* is now only the default value `*%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp*`. And when i run `npm install -g typescript` it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Clear npm's cache using this command to get rid of any broken failes.

```
npm cache clean
```

You might try to remove `node_modules` dir entirely and reinstall all packages.

As @bluesman suggested, try to further debug the problem by setting npm log level to verbose.

```
npm config set loglevel verbose
```

Log output:

> C:\Users\rineesh>npm install -g typescript npm info it worked if it ends with ok npm verb cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe', . . npm verb addNamed "1.5.3" is a plain semver version for typescript npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.5 .3.tgz not in flight; adding npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript- 1.5.3.tgz', npm verb addRemoteTarball 'ce35e55f75b7a8d0ed571b503bd0a57157e523f7' ]

This output suggests the issue might be similar to this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7590 . Try to run

```
npm config ls -l
```

and see if paths and variables have appropriate value. Check if any of values are set mutliple times.

Comment: is there any other way to install typescript manually? Since it is javascript can i copy the code to some folder or something?

Answer (score 0):

Set npm logs to verbose

```
npm config set loglevel verbose
```

Then run your install again and it should give you enough hints on what could be the problem.

Comment: `C:\Users\rineesh>npm install -g typescript
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
.
.
npm verb addNamed "1.5.3" is a plain semver version for typescript
npm verb addRemoteTarball https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-1.5
.3.tgz not in flight; adding
npm verb addRemoteTarball [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript/-/typescript-
1.5.3.tgz',
npm verb addRemoteTarball   'ce35e55f75b7a8d0ed571b503bd0a57157e523f7' ]`
| This is what i got. And it stuck with the '/'

Comment: I have tried to run this command too `npm install -g express-generator`. Then also facing the same problem.